# Authentication between two Kerberos

Tags: authentication, imap, kerberos, postfix-mta

I wanted to present a problem with the intention of asking for advice.

I'm not asking for a solution but I appreciate any idea how to attack the problem.

I have already managed some I tell them below.

**Problem:**

I have one server running Postfix with Cyrus Imap installed on a Centos 6.

The authentication is performed against an Active Directory 2003.

Customers who aceden from Windows have SSO with this service.

Now I want to add that also authenticate against another Kerberos. (MIT Kerberos on a Linux server).

All under the same domain.

**Ideas to fix it:**

1) 
*From Cyrus settings kerberos state both available.
The desired behavior is similar to the PAM stack (if one fails to auntentificar try another).
I see that this is possible
Also in this way I do not see such as Cyrus could choose between two possible keys (Windows or Linux).*

2) 
*Having two intancias Postfix with Cyrus Imap.
A user authenticates Linux instance and another instance authenticates Windows users.
That seems more next even I do not know much if for example there comes a external mail and would know which of the two delegate such mail.*

I appreciate any idea where to continue my research.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is serverfault.com
2. Cyrus and the implemented SASL version do not care what the KDC is as long as it is a KDC. So you rather put them in your `krb5.conf` or better yet, use DNS lookups.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I do not understand is like having a two KDC krb5.conf.
What I have seen are two options:
- Having more than one but belonging to a different realm.
- Having one slave is a copy of another for the same realm.
Neither serves to my problem.
Therefore, try to think of having two instances of Postfix with Cyrus Sals and that each has its corresponding krb5.conf.
The latter is not if possible.
Sorry you do not understand, but I'm dizzy with this matter.

Comment: @MariaJosé, after your edit you simply says that you want a redundant machine as a KDC for the same realm. Did you join that machine to the domain already and promoted it as DC with Samba 4. You are going to need this.